# Reset MongoDB root Password on Amazon Linux

Tags: mongodb, password-recovery

I have inherited a MongoDB and no one knows the root password. Is there a way to change it? I am running `MongoDB shell version: 3.2.17`.

I would like to back up the DB's but need access to see what's there first

Comment: You are in Linux or Windows platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to start your mongod to maintenance mode, without `--auth`. Then you can change root user password.